# Google Cloud Storage - Transfer file stalling

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Storage - Transfer (both immediate and scheduled) via url stalls with a status "calculating" on a 100mb file.  The file can be manually uploaded to the google data storage bucket.  The file is one of five, the other four files transfer successfully.  No errors are generated, the transfer will remain in "calculating" indefinitely.  Are there any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this problem?

This is not a service level problem, and is repeatable.

As advised, will take this to GCS support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming.  Contact Google for issues related to their infrastructure or try https://serverfault.com/ for help diagnosing network-related issues.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are using Storage Transfer Service to store file on a Google Cloud Storage Bucket. As per GCP documentation [1],  it is currently under no SLA and some performance fluctuations may occur.

You may want to try to re-upload your file later or check the source from where you are transferring it. (S3, an HTTP/HTTPS location or another bucket)

Clicking on the affected transfer also displays information about the status of the operation.

As the above comment states, this is a specific issue and you  may want to submit it to GCP support team.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview#service_level_agreement